# Xtext- doGenerate returns xtend symbolics when run as a warfile

Tags: java, tomcat, war, xtext

I am developing an Xtext project and in my `Generator.xtend` I produce a python script. It all works fine when I run the `ServerLaucher.xtend` in the Eclipse, but if I produce the `war` file and run it in the Tomcat, the script includes the xtend symbolics. This is my code which produces python script:

```
def compile(Main main)'''
  #! /usr/bin/env python
  ...

    «FOR to : main.takeoff» 
        takeoff = rospy.Publisher('/ardrone/takeoff', Empty, queue_size=1)

        while takeoff.get_num_connections() < 1:
            rospy.sleep(0.1)

        takeoff.publish(empty)
        rospy.sleep(5)
    «ENDFOR»
'''

override void doGenerate(Resource resource, IFileSystemAccess2 fsa, IGeneratorContext context) {
    var result = "";
    for(main : resource.allContents.toIterable.filter(Main)) {
        result = main.compile.toString; 
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

If run in the Eclipse, the result contains:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
takeoff = rospy.Publisher('/ardrone/takeoff', Empty, queue_size=1)

while takeoff.get_num_connections() < 1:
    rospy.sleep(0.1)

takeoff.publish(empty)
rospy.sleep(5)
```

While Tomcat produces:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
ï¿½FOR to : main.takeoffï¿½  
takeoff = rospy.Publisher('/ardrone/takeoff', Empty, queue_size=1)

while takeoff.get_num_connections() < 1:
    rospy.sleep(0.1)

takeoff.publish(empty)
rospy.sleep(5)
ï¿½ENDFORï¿½
```

EDIT:
This is my main `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.xtext:xtext-gradle-plugin:2.0.4'
    }
}

subprojects {
    ext.xtextVersion = '2.17.0'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    dependencies {
        compile platform("org.eclipse.xtext:xtext-dev-bom:${xtextVersion}")
    }

    apply plugin: 'org.xtext.xtend'
    apply from: "${rootDir}/gradle/source-layout.gradle"
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'

    group = 'ic.ac.uk.mydsl'
    version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'

    configurations.all {
        exclude group: 'asm'
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:
My build.gradle file in one of the subprojects:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.xtext:xtext-gradle-plugin:2.0.4'
    }
}

subprojects {
    ext.xtextVersion = '2.17.0'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }


    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.encoding = 'UTF-8' 
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    dependencies {
        compile platform("org.eclipse.xtext:xtext-dev-bom:${xtextVersion}")
    }

    apply plugin: 'org.xtext.xtend'
    apply from: "${rootDir}/gradle/source-layout.gradle"
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'

    group = 'ic.ac.uk.xdrone'
    version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'

    configurations.all {
        exclude group: 'asm'
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8' 
}
```

Comment: are you use you have a correct setup for encoding? (the default setup may not set on in gradle or maven)

Comment: => do you use maven or gradle. in both: what encoding have you configured there? what is your machines default encoding?

Comment: I use gradle (and maven as well I think cuz xtext requires it). I haven't changed encoding in any of these. I use default settings created with the project. How can I change it?

Comment: well the problem is: i have no idea how you have configured eclipse and which encodings the files have you have created

Comment: I belive they are all in encoding "windwos-1252". Can I change it "globally" or sth?

Comment: as i said: rightklick -> properties on files and projects. or on window preferences -> general -> workspace

Comment: I didn't know that I can do it for the whole folder as well. I've done it for every subdirectory and it seems it worked. My files have been a bit corrupted because of these old encoding but I think it gives good results now. Let me finish fixing and will see if it solved the problem completely.

Comment: Yes this is solved. Changing encoding for whole folder fixed the problem. Amazing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

in gradle you should set the encoding for the JavaTask. the Xtend Plugin should then pick this up. Make also sure the file has actually the correct encoding

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8' 
}
```

(or ISO-8859-1 or ...)

Comment: In which Gradle file? Cuz there is quite a few of them.

Comment: Also, I added build.gradle file in my post, cuz to be honest I don't know where should I add your code. I tried it before and it didn't work.

Comment: And how can I change file encoding itself. It is .xtend file.

Comment: usually in build.gradle (in subprojects, after applying the java plugin, and thus for all projects) - rightklick on the file you should be able to set encoding in the properties

Comment: I addded the code which u provided to main build.gradle and to subproject and also modified the encoding, as u said. But the result is still the same. I added the code of the build.fradle file in the post. I have a filling that maybe I have to modify another file, but to be honest don't know which as my knowledge about Gradle is pretty basic.

Comment: please share a reproducing hello would example. which os do you use. what is the standard encoding?

Comment: Win 10. Standard encoding is: windows-1251

Comment: => can you provide a hello world reproducing example?

Comment: Do you mean the example project which is created by default?